# Parse string to date of the form yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S

Tags: java

How to parse `String` to `Date` in Java?
I've written the following code:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");
Date from = null;
Date to = null;
try {
    from = df.parse(params.from);
    to =  df.parse(params.to);  
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it doesn't work. More precisely, I've received `ParseException` during the code execution. The following StackTrace is given:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "'2012-8-15 0:0:0.0'"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.site.db.dao.DailyProfitDaoImpl.getProfitByCurrency(DailyProfitDaoImpl.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.getProfitByCurrency(Unknown Source)
    at ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.site.db.dao.extractor.PlayerSummaryExtractor.extractData(PlayerSummaryExtractor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:448)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:396)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:458)
    at ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.commons.db.util.DblinkUtil.executeQuery(DblinkUtil.java:56)
    at ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.commons.db.util.DblinkUtil.executeQueryOnPlatform(DblinkUtil.java:35)
    at ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.commons.db.util.DblinkUtil$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1e2b9b93.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:628)
    at ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.commons.db.util.DblinkUtil$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$76d821ca.executeQueryOnPlatform(<generated>)
    at ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.site.db.dao.PlayerReportDaoImpl.getPlayerReportSummary(PlayerReportDaoImpl.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.getPlayerReportSummary(Unknown Source)
    at ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.site.controller.PlayersAllController.updateList(PlayersAllController.java:221)
    at ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.site.controller.PlayersAllController.getDataList(PlayersAllController.java:323)
    at ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.commons.utils.panel.TableController$TableList.get(TableController.java:122)
    at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.getRowData(ListDataModel.java:152)
    at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.setRowIndex(ListDataModel.java:186)
    at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.setWrappedData(ListDataModel.java:220)
    at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.<init>(ListDataModel.java:79)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.getDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.createDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:59)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataTable.createDataModel(UIDataTable.java:121)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.getExtendedDataModel(UIDataAdaptor.java:621)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.setRowKey(UIDataAdaptor.java:339)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.iterate(UIDataAdaptor.java:1017)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.processUpdates(UIDataAdaptor.java:1170)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.processUpdates(UIDataAdaptor.java:1182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1081)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:261)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot$2.invokeContextCallback(AjaxViewRoot.java:419)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:235)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processUpdates(AjaxViewRoot.java:435)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.site.web.filters.PartnerAccessFilter.doFilter(PartnerAccessFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.concurrent.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilterHttp(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice the little enclosing `'` single quotes. Those are not in your pattern `String`. Either remove them from the date `String` or add them to the pattern `String`.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("''yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S''"); // escaped
```

Comment: Why do you insert a "double single quotes" `''` instead of a single `'`?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv See the [javadoc of `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). The single quote is used to specify literals in the date `String`. It's therefore also used to escape `'` as a literal.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct. And observant!

## Time Zone

By the way, the question ignores the issue of time zone. That string will be parsed as if it represents a date-time in the JVM's current default time zone. That means results may vary. Better to explicitly specify the intended time zone.

## Joda-Time

Here's example code using the Joda-Time 2.4 library (much much better than using java.util.Date). Your string is close to the ISO 8601 standard for date-time string formats. Joda-Time uses that standard for its default in parsing and generating strings. So I'll simple replace the SPACE with the expected `T`.

```
String inputRaw = "2012-8-15 0:0:0.0";
String input = inputRaw.replace( " ", "T" );
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ); // As intended by the meaning of the input string.
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input, timeZone );
```

If you need a java.util.Date for other classes, convert from Joda-Time.

```
Java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```